# Cron job to location

Tags: php, mysql, cron, cron-task

I am trying to create a scheduled back up for my database, however on my hosting control panel it says:

`Run this command:`

then I have to type something in... I assumed this would be the link to the PHP script, so typed

`http://www.mydomain.com/location_of_script.php` however i am then shown the error `Could not find [link]

Can anyone help with this as I am new to Cron jobs?

Comment: If you want to do it based on the domain, use `wget http://location/ofscript.php` or something similar. Cron jobs run from Bash, so it has to be a valid Bash command. PHP may or may not be a valid script type, depending on the hosting company.

Comment: If you are just doing a backup onto the web server, try a cron job for mysqladmin (or whatever flavor you're using) instead of a web page that does the same. Less possible issues in the future.

Comment: @matcarlson - Thats not working either.

Comment: You may want to look into using Linux's built-in cron jobs - If you have SSH access to the server, you should be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a full path name for the file on the system.  Something like `/var/www/location_of_script.php`

Comment: I have tried `/var/www/dbs/backup.php` but still showing cannot find?

Comment: @user2149630 Is that the actual full file path? Does that file have permissions to be run by cron user?

Comment: it is on my server in a folder called db?

Comment: @user2149630 Yes. But what is the full file path to that folder?